# VSCode Error/Warning Validation Decoration Setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

10 shillings to whomever can tell me how to switch the error/warning decoration in vscode from a squiggly underline to an outline. It's what I am used to in Sublime Text, but I cannot seem to find the option to change it in vscode. Perhaps it is not possible? Knowing that would be a sufficient answer too.

[image]

Comment: You can vote for this issue : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9209

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there isn't a setting for this.

There IS an extension point for decorating text that would allow this, but as far as I know it isn't possible to access the errors for a file from the API to decorate the text. You can create new ones, but I don't believe it is possible to access existing errors.

tl;dr - I don't think this is possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

[`Microsoft/vscode issue 9209](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9209) points out more recently (2019/2020) to:

- [Error Gutter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IgorSbitnev.error-gutters): This is the VSCodium (or Visual Studio Code) version of error gutters available in other text editors, such as Sublime Text or Atom.
  [image: Gutter]

And:

- [Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens): ErrorLens turbo-charges language diagnostic features by making diagnostics stand out more prominently, highlighting the entire line wherever a diagnostic is generated by the language and also prints the message inline.
  [image: ErrorLens]